# Can you create new annotation feature classes with Python in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, annotation, arcgis-10.2

I am working on a project that needs to create file geodatabases from scratch and I cannot find any information about how to make new feature classes as annotation with Python.

Does anyone have any thoughts or suggestions on this? Is there another way to do this programmability outside of Python?

This question was written for ArcGIS Desktop 9.3 but Answers using ArcGIS 10 for Desktop are also welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid it doesn't look like you can edit anotation objects within Python. According to [this post](http://forums.esri.com/thread.asp?t=188208&f=1729&c=93#557900) the annotations are stored within Blob fields which are inaccessible from the Python geoprocessor. More than happy to be proved wrong here though!

As @Kirk Kuykendall says above, it's doable through arcobjects, maybe through an [IAnnotationFeature](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriCarto/IAnnotationFeature.htm).

Comment: You are exactly right except for the IAnnotationFeature part, which (although related to annotations) will not help you when creating a feature class containing annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try [Append Annotation Feature Classes](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=append_annotation_feature_classes_%28data_management%29) with an empty input annotation featureclass.  Or it can be done programmatically with arcobjects.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your initial empty file geodatabase annotation feature class through ArcCatalog and then use the **[Feature Class To Feature Class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000020000000)** tool in a Python script to create subsequent ones.